# Open Source Tools for MDA/MDD

Tags: eclipse-emf, mda, mdd

I need to do some research in MDA/MDD to find Open-Source-Tools which will help me to develop code-generators and transformators.
But there are only a few tools which are actually supported. Do I search in the wrong direction?

Do You know open source tools for MDA/MDD?

Greetings Dominic

I found andromda, Eclipse Modelling Framework and a few tools like plantuml, which help to create diagrams .

My plan is to read diagrams with plantuml and convert them with emf to code and the reverse way.

Answer (score 0):

Telosys could be a solution to your need (https://doc.telosys.org/)
Telosys has its own DSL to define the models (based on text files with a simple grammar), see https://doc.telosys.org/dsl-model
A Telosys model can be used to generate any kind of target language (including PlantUML) but Telosys cannot parse PlantUML files, so the input model must be a Telosys model (or a database schema if you create the model from a relational DB).